# Multiple onchange="this.form.submit()" on one page not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have two forms both using select so my values are within  dropdown. I want to be able to submit the two forms without the use of submit buttons.

The first form submits using the `onchange="this.form.submit()"`

method. However, the second form doesn't submit when an option selected.

How do I make each form submit using `onchange="this.form.submit()"`?

```
//This form submits using onchange="this.form.submit()"

<select class="clientselect" name="clientlist" id="clientlist" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">All Clients</option>
        <? echo makeClientList($conn); ?>
    </select>

//This for does'nt sybmit using onchange="this.form.submit()"

<select class="clientselect" name="filterstatus" id="filterstatus" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">Filter by Status</option>
        <? echo getStatus($conn); ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Where is the declaration of your form tags? I can only see two selects in your code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give each form a `name` attribute then you can reference that in your `onchange`, for example:

```
onchange="document.form1.submit()"
```

You'll need to change `form1` for the `name` of each form